# How to change view Project Explorer tree in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, project-explorer

I want to change from this '>' to this '+'

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse (SWT) uses native controls for trees (that is a control provided by the operating system).
The tree expand / collapse images are part of the native control and can't be changed in Eclipse.

So this can't be done (unless the operating system control provides some way to do it)

Comment: I see this difference between my PC Windows 64 bit and laptop Windows 7 32 bit. Thanks!

Comment: I believe this is just different styles available in th different releases of Windows. Project Explorer doesn't provide any way to change this.